# Dismiss $uibModal from within

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap's $uibModal to make forms in my web-application. Everything works fine, except that I cannot close the dialog after it's been shown.

I spent two days trying not to post here such a simple question, especially when there was a lot of answers for the same error that I'm receiving, i.e.

> "**Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <-
>   ModalInstanceCtrl**".

To have some ease in operating with huge application, I divided my code into separate files, also I use 'controller as' style in htmls, so, there's no $scopes in the code.

No matter what I do, I keep receiving this error that I mentioned before.
What I need, is to close the dialog after user have successfully logged in.

**index.html:**

```
...
    <script src="rf/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="rf/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="rf/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="rf/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

    <!-- Project files -->
    <script src="application.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="frmLogin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Load things into this division -->
    <div ng-include src="loaderCtrl.cFragment" ng-app="dgis" ng-controller="applicationController as loaderCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

**application.js**

```
var myApp = angular
  .module('dgis', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller("applicationController", ['$http', '_gl', '$uibModal', function ($http, _gl, $uibModal) {
      _gl.AppReference = this;

      // Enable animations
      this.animationsEnabled = true;

      // Declare modal window
      this.showFrmLogin = function (size) {
         var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: this.animationsEnabled,
              templateUrl: 'frmLogin.html',
              controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
              size: size,
              backdrop: 'static',
              keyboard: false,
              resolve: {
                  items: function () {
                      return this.items;
                  }
              }
          });
      };

      this.showFrmLogin();
```

**frmLogin.js**

```
myApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['_gl', '$uibModalInstance', function (_gl, $uibModalInstance) {

    this.login = function () {        
        angular.forEach(some_array, function (element) {
            if (something == element)                   
               // This code executes successfully and shows the page
               _gl.AppReference.cFragment = "frmMain.html";
               // This line does not close the dialog
               $uibModalInstance.close('a');
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

And **_gl** - is a service that I use to hold global variables

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use $rootScope

when initializing your modal use $rootScope.modalInstance

You can access it anywhere from the application then.
Hope this helps

---

1. **Remove the $uibModalInstance references**
2. Instead of "var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({"

   **Use "$rootScope.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({**
3. Instead of $uibModalInstance.close('a');"

   **Use "$rootScope.modalInstance.close('a');"**

Comment: ,"Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- ModalInstanceCtrl".

Comment: remove $uibModalInstance from the parameter list  in ModalInstanceCtrl

Comment: then how am I supposed to close the dialog?

Comment: myApp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['_gl', ' $rootScope', function (_gl, $rootScope) {

    this.login = function () {        
        angular.forEach(some_array, function (element) {
            if (something == element)                   
               // This code executes successfully and shows the page
               _gl.AppReference.cFragment = "frmMain.html";
               // This line does not close the dialog
             $rootScope.modalInstance.close();
            }
        });
    }
}]);

Comment: and In the applicationController 
instead of  var modalInstance

make it $rootScope.modalInstance

Comment: I used var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({ ...options });  Then I closed it with modalInstance.close();